# Asignar nueva propiedad a Arreglo de Objetos Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, estructuras-de-datos, objeto

Consideremos la siguiente situación.

La App va a recibir un `array` de `objects` de longitud `n`, con una estructura similar a la siguiente:

```
[{ 
   titulo:"any",
   mensaje:"any"
 },
 { 
   titulo:"any",
   mensaje:"any"
 },
 { 
   titulo:"any",
   mensaje:"any"
 },
//...longitud n
 { 
   titulo:"any",
   mensaje:"any"
 }
]
```

Lo que se busca, es asignar una nueva propiedad `id` a esta estructura, para que se transforme de la siguiente forma:

```
[{ 
       id:0,
       titulo:"any",
       mensaje:"any"
     },
     { 
       id:1,
       titulo:"any",
       mensaje:"any"
     },
     { 
       id:2,
       titulo:"any",
       mensaje:"any"
     },
    //...longitud n
    { 
       id:n,
       titulo:"any",
       mensaje:"any"
     }
    ]
```

> Nótese que se conoce la longitud del array

Estoy investigando cual es la forma más práctica de obtener esta transformación, he intentado usar ciclos, el operador `elipsis`, también con el método `Object.assign`, pero me esta costando trabajo, espero contar con su apoyo.

Comment: Lo siento por molestar, pero... el de tu foto de perfil es el hermano de gilbert(anime: violet evergarden)??

Comment: El mismo, son muy agradables los visuales del anime, ¿Quien esta en tu perfil fire emblem? saludos

Comment: Violet Evergarden es uno de mis animes favoritos y le tengo mucho cariño, tanto por la historia como por la animación. El de mi foto de perfil corresponde al anime "Sousei no omniouji" ^_^

Comment: Violet es mi `Waifu`, que bueno que habemos muchos fans, ya puse Sousei no omniouji en mi lista, saludos colega.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con un for se podría hacer. Una cosa extraña que note es que las propiedades de los objetos no se denotan como variables en vez de `id=0` debería ser `id: 0`, creo que tu principal error es ese

```js
    let array = [{
       titulo: "any",
       mensaje: "any"
     },
     {
       titulo: "any",
       mensaje: "any"
     },
     {
       titulo: "any",
       mensaje: "any"
     },
     {
       titulo: "any",
       mensaje: "any"
     }
    ]
    
    
    for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
      const element = array[i]
      element.id = i
    }
    
    console.log(array)
```

Comment: Error de dedo, ya modifiqué la pregunta, estoy analizando tu respuesta, saludos.

Comment: .@Franco, la respuesta me es de utilidad solo tengo una duda ¿Porque se tiene `let id` en closure? bien se podría asignar el índice del `for` a `element.id`, saludos

Comment: Está bien, se ve más inteligible, saludos

Comment: otra opción: `array.forEach((element, index) => element.id=index);`

Comment: Interesante patrón @PabloLozano, gracias por compartir.

Answer (score 1):

Tengo conocimiento de que la función *map* es la más optima para este tipo de situaciones

Hice el siguiente código de prueba:

```js
let arr = [{name: 'a', des: 'a2'}, {name: 'a', des: 'a2'}, {name: 'a', des: 'a2'}]
                                                                                
arr.map((elemento, index) => elemento.id = index)
//Donde "elemento" es cada objeto del array e "index" es la posición        
                                                                                 
console.log(arr)
```

Lo cual te va a arrojar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fuente: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map

Comment: Voy a revisar tu código y te envío mis comentarios, saludos

Comment: .@Alejandro Milan, Supongamos que yo quiero usar la copia que regresa `map`, es decir `let slidesCopy = slides.map...`, ¿Cómo haces para incluir todas las propiedades de cada elemento en la copia? Si pudieras actualizar la respuesta con esta modificación.

Answer (score 0):

Se puede usar el método `map` con propagación:

```
let arrayCopy = array.map((item, index) => ({...item, id:index}));
```