# Me gustaria saber como cerrar una serie de ventanas modales en react, lo que deseo es que cuando se habra una se cierre la anterior

Tags: reactjs, web

```
export const Labels = ({ id, content, color }) => {
  const [changeColor, setChangeColor] = useState(false);

  const hanldeChange = () => {};

  return (
    <>
      <div className="px-3 border-2 border-blur-lg flex justify-between m-5 rounded-md">
        <div className="flex py-3">
          <BlockColor color={color} />
          <input
            type="text"
            id="txtLabel"
            name="txtLabel"
            className="text-base ring-white focus:ring-transparent mx-3 text-gray-700 outline-none"
            value={content}
            onChange={hanldeChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="flex py-3">
          <button className="mx-2">
            <img
              src={`./assets/Pantone.svg`}
              alt="New Label"
              onClick={() => setChangeColor(!changeColor)}
            />
          </button>
          <button className="mx-3">
            <img src={`./assets/Delete.svg`} alt="Delete" />
          </button>
          <ModalColor
            changeColorState={changeColor}
            setChangeColorState={setChangeColor}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Es un componente modal que recibe 3 propiedades, id, contenido y color.
esto se genera de forma dinamica y cada "label" tiene un id, contenido y color.
entonces, cuando presionan un boton este dispara otro modal que presenta los colores disponibles.
Cada vez que hacen click sobre el boton para cambiar el color la venatana se abre  y si van a otro label y presionan otra vez se abre una nueva lo que quiero saber es como hacer para que se cuando se abre una ventana modal para seleccionar el color, y se encuentra abierta otra ventana modal para seleccionar un color esta se cierre.

```
export const ModalColor = ({ changeColorState, setChangeColorState }) => {


    const [blockColor, setBlockColor] = useState("#409FFF");

    const handleColorChange = (e) => {
         setBlockColor(e.target.value);
        setChangeColorState(false);
    };

    return (
        <>
            {changeColorState && (
                <div className="container absolute bg-white -right-2 top-auto mt-7 shadow-lg border-2 w-64 m-5 rounded-md overflow-x-hidden">
                    <p className="mx-2 text-gray-700 font-medium">Change Color</p>
                    <div className="mx-3 grid grid-cols-5 gap-4 my-2 rounded-full">
                        <input
                            type="radio"
                            className="cursor-pointer form-radio h-6 w-6 text-rojo"
                            value="#FD7972"
                            checked
                            readOnly
                            onClick={handleColorChange}
                        />

                        <input
                            type="radio"
                            value="#FE9F5E"
                            checked
                            readOnly
                            onClick={handleColorChange}
                            className="cursor-pointer form-radio h-6 w-6 text-naranja"
                        />

                        <input
                            type="radio"
                            value="#FFD454"
                            checked
                            readOnly
                            onClick={handleColorChange}
                            className="cursor-pointer form-radio h-6 w-6 text-amarillo"
                        />

                    </div>
                    <p>{blockColor}</p>
                </div>
            )}
        </>
    );
};
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se debe trabajar con el `id` de cada objeto `Label`.

Suponiendo que se puede [acceder y modificar la estructura del array `Labels`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/430926/asignar-nueva-propiedad-a-arreglo-de-objetos-javascript) en el `parent component`, se podría agregar una nueva propiedad `hide` para cada objeto `Labels`:

```
  //Pseudo estructura Labels con nueva propiedad hide
  [{"id":1 ,"hide":false},
  {"id":2,"hide":false},
  {"id":3,"hide":false},
  {"id":4,"hide":false}]
```

Una vez que se obtenga la modificación de dicha estructura, el estado de `Labels` se puede manejar con React:

```
const [labels, setLabels] = useState([{"id":1 ,"hide":false},
  {"id":2,"hide":false},
  {"id":3,"hide":false},
  {"id":4,"hide":false}]);
```

---

#### Ocultar ModalColor por id

A continuación, el componente `Labels` se debe estar armando más o menos de la siguiente forma desde su `parent component`:

```
    {
      labels.map((elem) => {
       return <Labels key={elem.id} id={elem.id} hide={elem.hide} handleHideModal={handleHideModal} />
      })
    }
```

Aquí, se propagan dos nuevas props, `hide` que es la propiedad que se agrego al array `Labels` y `handleHideModal`, un método que servirá para modificar el valor de `hide`.

Después, el método `handleHideModal` espera recibir el `id` de cada `Labels->label`, con ese dato se modifica el estado de `Labels`, en especifico el valor de `hide` para el `id` recibido.

Nótese que se dispara un `re render` para devolver el componente nuevamente con el nuevo estado para `Labels`:

```
    function handleHideModal(id){
          
          let labelsCopy = labels.map((elem) => {
              if(elem.id === id){
                elem.hide = true;
              } else {
                elem.hide = false;
              }
              return elem;
          })
          //re render
          setLabels(labelsCopy);
    }
```

Luego, en el componente `Labels`, se captura el evento `handleColorModal` con su respectivo `id` para cada `Labels->Label`:

```
<button onClick={()=>handleColorModal(props.id)}>Set color</button>
```

Finalmente, se propaga `hide` hacia el componente `ModalColor` desde su correspondiente `Label` Component (por `id`) y se usa un operador ternario para validar cuando se oculta y cuando se muestra:

```
function ModalColor({id, hide}){
    return (!hide) ? null : <p>Muestra modal de Change Colors</p>;
}
```

---

Demo:

```js
function App(){
  const [labels, setLabels] = React.useState([{"id":1 ,"hide":false},
  {"id":2,"hide":false},
  {"id":3,"hide":false},
  {"id":4,"hide":false}]);

  function handleHideModal(id){
      
      let labelsCopy = labels.map((elem) => {
          if(elem.id === id){
            elem.hide = true;
          } else {
            elem.hide = false;
          }
          return elem;
      })
      
      setLabels(labelsCopy);
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
    {
      labels.map((elem) => {
       return <Labels key={elem.id} id={elem.id} hide={elem.hide} handleHideModal={handleHideModal} />
      })
    }
    </div>
  );
}

function Labels(props){

  function handleColorModal(id){
    props.handleHideModal(id);
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
    <p>Modal {props.id} </p>
    <button onClick={()=>handleColorModal(props.id)}>Set color</button>
    <ModalColor
            id={props.id}
            hide={props.hide}
          />
    </div>
  )
}

function ModalColor({id, hide}){
    console.log(`id:${id},hide:${hide}`);
    return (!hide) ? null : <p>Mostrar modal change color</p>;
}


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puede hacer una condición o un setState booleano en el cual setees show: true cuando quieras que muestre y luego show: false cuando haya terminado la accion del modal. En este link tienes mas info https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-open-and-close-react-bootstrap-modal-programmatically,

Espero te sirva, saludos!

Comment: Bienvenid@ a [es.so], te recomiendo leer [answer] para que mejores tu respuesta y agregues más detalles ya que por el momento parece ser una opinión o sugerencia.