# ¿Cómo saber en cual item hice click para modificar el resto?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, redux, react-redux

Tengo este código donde tengo una lista de elementos y al hacer clic cambio un poco el estilo del botón en el cual hice clic(agrego un clase llamada `active`), pero al hacer clic en alguno quiero que el resto de los botones queden como originalmente están(sin la clase `active`):

```js
//import {useState} from 'react'
const {useState} = React;

function ButtonItem() {
  const [btnclick, setBtnClick] = useState(false)
  return (
  <button
    className={btnclick ? `active` : ``}
    onClick={() => setBtnClick(!btnclick)}>
    &#9733;
  </button>)
}

function App() {
  const list = ['item 1','item 2','item 3','item 4']
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
      {list.map(item=>(
        <li key={item}>
          {item}
          <ButtonItem />
        </li>
      ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

button{
  background: black;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
button.active{
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Cabe aclarar que este es un pequeño ejemplo que hice para mostrar lo que intento hacer pero el botón en cuestión podría no ser hijo directo de `li` y podría estar más adentro en un árbol de componentes. Ojala me puedan ayudar.

Como dato extra, estoy utilizando `redux` en mi proyecto, no sé si sea necesario incluirlo para solucionar este problema

Answer (score 1):

Se puede transformar a objeto cada elemento de la lista y [agregar dos nuevas propiedades](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/430926/asignar-nueva-propiedad-a-arreglo-de-objetos-javascript), `active` y `id` que serán usadas como bandera `boolean` e identifcador para cada `bótón`:

```
const listData = [
    {title:'item 1',active:false, id:1},
    {title:'item 2',active:false, id:2},
    {title:'item 3',active:false, id:3},
    {title:'item 4',active:false, id:4}
];
```

También, se crea un nuevo estado `list` y se inicializa con la lista:

```
const [list, setList] = useState(listData);
```

Luego, se pasan 3 props al componente `ButtonItem`:

```
<ButtonItem 
      id={item.id}
      active={item.active}
      btnHandler={handleBtn}
/>
```

Donde:

- id : se usa el parámetro `id` de cada elemento de la lista
- active : se pasa la bandera de estado de cada elemento de la lista
- btnHandler : se pasa una función handle

Enseguida, desde el componente `ButtonItem`, se pasa el `id` de cada botón como argumento a la función `btnHandler`:

```
<button
    className={active ? `active` : ``}
    onClick={() => btnHandler(id)}>
    &#9733;
</button>
```

Finalmente, el evento `onClick` se maneja en `btnHanlder` usando `map`, donde se evalua por `id` y se modifica la propiedad `active`; se obtiene un nuevo arreglo con las modificaciones necesarias por `id` y se ejecuta el `set` del estado `list`:

```
function handleBtn(id){
    let filterRes = list.map(item => {
       (item.id === id) ? item.active = true : item.active = false;
       return item;
    });
    setList(filterRes);
}
```

El componente se devuelve nuevamente ya con el comportamiento esperado en el color de cada botón.

Demo:

```js
function ButtonItem({id, active, btnHandler}) {
  return (
  <button
    className={active ? `active` : ``}
    onClick={() => btnHandler(id)}>
    &#9733;
  </button>)
}

function App() {
  const listData = [
    {title:'item 1',active:false, id:1},
    {title:'item 2',active:false, id:2},
    {title:'item 3',active:false, id:3},
    {title:'item 4',active:false, id:4}
  ];
  const [list, setList] = React.useState(listData);

  function handleBtn(id){
    let filterRes = list.map(item => {
       (item.id === id) ? item.active = true : item.active = false;
       return item;
    });
    setList(filterRes);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
      {list.map((item)=>(
        <li key={item.id}>
          {item.title}
          <ButtonItem 
            id={item.id}
            active={item.active}
            btnHandler={handleBtn}
          />
        </li>
      ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
button{
  background: black;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
button.active{
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: suponiendo que el botón se encuentra dentro del arbol de componentes(si hubiera más) hasta el fondo , tendría que pasar `handleBtn` por cada componente hasta llegar al que necesito cierto?

Comment: Así es, necesitas hacer `props drilling`.  Se puede pensar en implementar `context`, pero sera un grado más de complejidad pues también tienes `redux` por ahi. Por ejemplo, suponiendo que el estado `list` viene de `redux store`, `handleBtn` necesitaría invocar a un `dispatch` y así (es el único cambio significativo que tendrías que hacer), pero combinarle el `context` a `redux` si es más reto. Creo que mi respuesta se queda corta, pues tu diseño parece más complejo. Si logro algo con context te actualizo la respuesta, suerte colega.