# ¿Cómo agregar un elemento a un array de objetos JSON con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, jsonarray

Que debo hacer para agregar un elemento a un array de objetos JSON con JavaScript, por ejemplo tengo este array de objetos en JSON

```
[
    {
        "id_alumno": 1
    },
    {
        "id_alumno": 2
    },
    {
        "id_alumno": 3
    },
    {
        "id_alumno": 4
    }
]
```

Cómo le agrego a cada objeto un nuevo elemento por ejemplo **grupo 2**, para que quede de la siguiente forma

```
[
    {
        "id_alumno": 1
        "grupo": 2

    },
    {
        "id_alumno": 2
        "grupo": 2
    },
    {
        "id_alumno": 3
        "grupo": 2
    },
    {
        "id_alumno": 4
        "grupo": 2
    }
]
```

puede ser con cualquier framework de javascript

Comment: Si no te  importa modificar el objeto original puedes usar un forEach como `arreglo.forEach(obj => obj.grupo = 2)` tan simple como eso. Si no quieres modificar el objeto original usa un map `let newArreglo = arreglo.map(obj => {return {...obj, grupo: 2}})`.

Comment: De cualquier manera tienes como 10 formas diferentes de hacerlo con `for(...in...)`, con  `for(...of...)`, con un `for` tradicional, con un `while`, con `.foreEch`, con `.map`, con `reduce`, modificando o no el arreglo original, en fin, busca y elige la que más entiendas, pero sobretodo, investiga y aprende. Ahh, y para ninguno ocupas framework ni nada por el estilo, es simple javascript nativo.

Comment: [Pregunta con respuesta relacionada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/430927/101408)