# Get imagenes React

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, redux

Tengo una app para hacer peticiones post y get a un servidor, el cual almacena imágenes y las obtengo de acuerdo a un id, el problema es que al obtener la imagen me muestra las del id anterior y tengo que hacer click muchas veces para que me muestre la correcta.

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-buck-ovxmp?file=/src/App.js)

GET C#

```html
 [HttpGet("{IdCat}/{Id}")]
        public ActionResult Get(int IdCat, int Id)
        {
            try
            {
                var foto = _context.ModelFotos.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IdCat == IdCat && x.Id==Id);
                string Imagen = getFile(foto.Ruta);
                return Ok(Imagen);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return BadRequest(e.Message);
            }
        }

        public string getFile(string ruta)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] bytesImagen = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(ruta);
                string imagenBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesImagen);
                string tipoContenido;
                switch (Path.GetExtension(ruta))
                {
                    case ".jpg":
                        {
                            tipoContenido = "image/jpg";
                            break;
                        }
                    case ".gif":
                        {
                            tipoContenido = "image/gif";
                            break;
                        }
                    case ".jepg":
                        {
                            tipoContenido = "image/jepg";
                            break;
                        }
                    case ".png":
                        {
                            tipoContenido = "image/png";
                            break;
                        }
                    case ".jfif":
                        {
                            tipoContenido = "image/jfif";
                            break;
                        }
                    default:
                        {
                            return null;
                        }
                }
                return string.Format("data:{0};base64,{1}", tipoContenido, imagenBase64);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.ToString();
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Get React

```html
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Box, Collapse } from "@material-ui/core";
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import KeyboardArrowDownIcon from '@material-ui/icons/KeyboardArrowDown';
import KeyboardArrowUpIcon from '@material-ui/icons/KeyboardArrowUp';
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  const [detailsopen, setdetailsopen] = useState([]);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [fotos, setFotos] = useState([
    {
      "id": 441,
      "descripcion": "Equipo de proteccion"
    },
    {
      "id": 442,
      "descripcion": "Lavamanos"
    },
    {
      "id": 443,
      "descripcion": "Politica"
    },
    {
      "id": 444,
      "descripcion": "Sanitarios"
    }
  ]);
  const [id, setId] = useState("");
  const [rutaFile, setRutaFile] = useState(null);
  const { IdCat} = useParams();

  const toggleShown = i => {
    setId(i);
    const shownState = detailsopen.slice();
    const index = shownState.indexOf(id);
    if (index >= 0) {
      shownState.splice(index, 1);
      getFoto(id);
      setdetailsopen(shownState);
    }
    else {
      shownState.push(id);
      setdetailsopen(shownState);
      setOpen(true)
    }
  }

  const getFoto = async (id) => {
    await axios.get("www.mysite.mx/"+id)
      .then(res => {
        setRutaFile(res.data);
      })
  }
  
return (

<div className="App">
<div className="table-responsive table-condensed table-sm">
<table
className="table table-hover table-sm table-striped"
>
<thead>
<tr className="table-primary">
<th>Fotografía</th>
<th>Descripción</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{fotos.map((item) => (
<>
<tr key={item.id}>
<td>
<IconButton aria-label="expand row" size="small" 
onClick={() => toggleShown(item.id)}>
{open ? <KeyboardArrowUpIcon /> : <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />}
</IconButton>
</td>
<td>{item.descripcion}
</td>
</tr>
{detailsopen.includes(item.id) && (
<tr>
{id === item.id ?
<td style={{ paddingBottom: 0, paddingTop: 0 }} colSpan={5}>
<Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
<Box margin={1}>
<table size="small" aria-label="purchases">
<tbody>
<img style={{ width: '50%', height: '50%' }}
id="foto"
src={rutaFile}
alt=""
/>
</tbody>
</table>
</Box>
</Collapse>
</td>
: null}
</tr>
)}
</>
))}
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
);
}
```

Comment: ¿Tienes un repositorio para esta app? Saludos

Comment: @g.4 he editado mi pregunta

Comment: ¿Tienes permitido modificar la estructura de `fotos`? Tengo una solución basada en una nueva propiedad para cada objeto en `fotos`, saludos

Comment: @g.4 si claro puedo hacerlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede modificar la estructura de `fotos`, agregando una nueva propiedad `isOpen` para cada elemento con valor `false`:

```
{
  "id": 441,
  "descripcion": "Equipo de proteccion",
  "isOpen":false
}
```

[Asignar nueva propiedad a Arreglo de Objetos Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/430926/asignar-nueva-propiedad-a-arreglo-de-objetos-javascript)

Luego, se modifica el `JSX` para hacer una validación usando esta nueva propiedad `isOpen`, donde el botón toggle mostrará su estado:

```
<IconButton aria-label="expand row" size="small" 
onClick={() => toggleShown(item.id)}>
{item.isOpen ? <KeyboardArrowUpIcon /> : <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />}
</IconButton>
```

Entonces, como la propiedad `isOpen` es parte de `fotos`, se puede usar como expresión dentro del ciclo `map` en `JSX`:

```
<tbody>
{fotos.map((item) => (
    <>
    <tr key={item.id}>
        <td>
            <IconButton aria-label="expand row" size="small" 
            onClick={() => toggleShown(item.id)}>
            {item.isOpen ? <KeyboardArrowUpIcon /> : <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />}
            </IconButton>
        </td>
        <td>{item.descripcion}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style={{ paddingBottom: 0, paddingTop: 0 }} colSpan={5}>
        <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
        <Box margin={1}>
        <table size="small" aria-label="purchases">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <img style={{ width: '50%', height: '50%' }}
                    id="foto"
                    src={rutaFile}
                    alt=""
                    />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </Box>
        </Collapse>
    </td>
    </tr>
</>
))}
</tbody>
```

Enseguida, la forma en que se usa el estado `rutaFile`, puede cambiar un poco, usando el `operador ternario` para validar si contiene una ruta:

```
<td>
    {rutaFile ? <img style={{ width: '50%', height: '50%' }}
     id="foto"
     src={rutaFile}
     alt=""
     />: null}
</td>
```

Finalmente, la función `toggleShown` puede quedar de la siguiente forma, se crea una copia del estado `fotos` basado en cual foto es la que se quiere mostrar en el menú toggle:

```
const toggleShown = i => {
    setRutaFile(null);
    let auxArray = fotos.map(e=>{
      (e.id === i ) ? e.isOpen = true : e.isOpen = false;
      return e;
    });
    setFotos(auxArray);
    getFoto(i);
}
```

Y como la función `getFoto` se va a llamar en cada evento `toggle`, y solo necesita el parámetro `id`, se queda igual:

```
const getFoto = async (id) => {
    await axios.get("www.mysite.mx/"+id)
    .then(res => {
        setRutaFile(res.data);
    })
}
```

Cuando se ejecuta `setRutaFile`, no solo se devuelve el componente con la ruta específica para cada `descripcion`, si no que también, todo el estado `fotos` con las banderas `isOpen` en su estado actual.

#### Notas de campo

- Estos cambios funcionan en el repositorio que compartes.
- Si se usa `redux`, puede que tengas que implementar los cambios de estado con la secuencia useSelector->dispatch->action. Ya que `redux-store` es el dueño del estado.
- Solo tienes que migrar los cambios de estado para su uso con el patrón redux.

Espero que esta resuesta sea de ayuda.